# Query to sort data from a MYSQL 8 table

Tags: mysql

I request your kind support with the following case.
I have this score table as follows:

```
create table score (idscore int primary key auto_increment,
                    ndeporte varchar(45),
                    category varchar(45),
                    gender varchar(45),
                    team1 varchar(45),
                    score1 int,
                    team2 varchar(45),
                    score2 int,
                    team3 varchar(45),
                    score3 varchar(45)
```

)

**MY SCORE TABLE**
[image: MY SCORE TABLE]

**NOW I WANT TO GET THIS RESULT.**

[image: DESIRABLE TABLE]

I have doubts on how to order my data from my table so that it shows as well as the image.
I request your kind support

I am working on MYSQL 8

Comment: Please answer to all comments from [previous copy of your question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/249455/stored-procedure-to-display-ordered-data-in-mysql).

Comment: @akina I already answered you, please your support with this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it directly:

```
SELECT idscore,
       ndeporte,
       category,
       gender,
       'ROJO' team1,
       CASE WHEN team1 = 'ROJO' THEN score1
            WHEN team2 = 'ROJO' THEN score2
            WHEN team3 = 'ROJO' THEN score3
            END score1,
       'AMARILLO' team2,
       CASE WHEN team1 = 'AMARILLO' THEN score1
            WHEN team2 = 'AMARILLO' THEN score2
            WHEN team3 = 'AMARILLO' THEN score3
            END score2,
       'TURQUESA' team3,
       CASE WHEN team1 = 'TURQUESA' THEN score1
            WHEN team2 = 'TURQUESA' THEN score2
            WHEN team3 = 'TURQUESA' THEN score3
            END score1
FROM score;
```

Comment: thank you dear @Akina

Comment: I have a question if I want to get the total of each score as I could.